# System.debug line hitting CPU Time Limit

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, after-trigger

I am facing weird challenge, when I use these debug statements in my AFTER UPDATE Trigger
am hitting CPU Time Limit,if I comment them out am not facing that,
any inputs on this will be appreciated

```
trigger MyTrigger on Account(after update) {



list < AccountShare > newAccountShares = new list < AccountShare > ();
set < id > userids = new set < id > ();
set < id > accids = new set < id > ();
set < id > AcctIds = new set < id > ();
set < Id > contactIds = new Set < Id > ();
set <id> ActIds = new set <id>();
boolean confi=false;

List < account > AccountsToUpdate = new list < account > ();
boolean ConfiCheck;
Map < String, Schema.SObjectType > sObjectMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType s = sObjectMap.get('Account');
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult resSchema = s.getDescribe();
Map < String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo > recordTypeInfo = resSchema.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
string CustAccId = recordTypeInfo.get('CustTest').getRecordTypeId();
CustAccId = CustAccId.substring(0, 15);
Set < id > confidentialId = new set < id > ();

for (account a1: trigger.new) {
   
    if (a1.Recordtypeid != CustAccId) {

        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            for (Account acc: trigger.old) {
                if (acc.custField__c != null) {
                    
                    contactIds.add(acc.custField__c);
                    
                    if (acc.custField2__c != null)
                        AcctIds.add(acc.custField2__c);
                }
            }
        }
        for (Account acc: trigger.new) { 
            if (acc.custField__c != null) {
                contactIds.add(acc.custField__c);
                if (acc.custField2__c != null)
                    AcctIds.add(acc.custField2__c);
            }
          
            if (acc.ownerId != trigger.oldmap.get(acc.id).ownerId) {
               accids.add(acc.id);
           system.debug('account'+acc);
                if(accids.size()>0){   
                AccountHandlerClass accRecCreate = new AccountHandlerClass();
                accRecCreate.CreateAccount(accids);
                
            
                  }
            }
        }
        

  
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show the code before `System.debug`?

Comment: Turning on the debug trace flags changes the  behaviour of the (slows down) the entire Apex runtime so if you were also doing that it would make a substantial difference. But only commenting those lines out is harder to explain. If you are close to hitting the governor limits, best to re-design or refactor now before you hit the problem in production. The only time I'ver seen the `System.debug` lines make a big difference is when `JSON.serialize` is used to output complete, large graphs of records instead of the default `toString()` logic that only outputs a brief excerpt.

Comment: add code for referance @KeithC ,

Comment: added code @PiotrGajek

Comment: I would avoid use of `System.getGlobalDescribe` if possible as this is very poorly performing. Since you are only accessing `Account` Schema detail, why not use static access to the Account SObjectType's describe?

Comment: you are doing a for loop inside of a for loop where if the batch size is 200 records means 200*200 = 40,000 iterations (and you do it twice).   Use maps

Comment: @KeithC FYI, even though it prints out much smaller, it still does an entire serialization, even if the log is never written to. This can have catastrophic performance characteristics, which is why I recommend never leaving system debug messages in a direct code path. The JSON.serialize call makes it even worse, because it is terribly inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone, i have one doubt, if i print trigger.new in for loop using system.debug method , and if i update 200 records using dataloder ,will this printing take much time?